# MFC OnPaint CButton

Tags: mfc

How do you assign a bitmap in OnPaint a button? can you use dcMemory to call it somewhere else?

```
CPaintDC dc(this); 

CBitmap bmp, *poldbmp;
CDC Refinery;



//load the bitmap resouce
bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);


    //create a compataible memory DC
Refinery.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc);


//Select the bitmap into DC
poldbmp = Refinery.SelectObject( &bmp);


//Copy (BitBlt) bitmap from memory DC to screen DC
dc.BitBlt(10,10,100, 100, &Refinery,0, 0, SRCCOPY);

Refinery.SelectObject(poldbmp);
```

Comment: Can you perhaps rephrase your question? Why isn't [CBitmapButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3y45xs0(v=vs.80).aspx) sufficient for your use?

Answer (score 0):

You question is really not clear. And it is a very bad idea to make the Load of a Bitmap everytime the WM_PAINT message is processed which tends to be ALWAYS!

If you need a button that has a bitmap, I recommend you to use `CMFCButton`. You only have to declare a variable of that type and do a `DDX_CONTROL` of it. I used them and I can also change the image they present after the first time I set it.